# Advanced querying in Parse's Push System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, parse-platform

I'm using [adelevie's parse-ruby-client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client) from my API.

I've managed so far to make an AND query between channels, but I've tried to make more complex queries, like the one you could build in Parse itself:

[image]

Here you can even add more conditions.
What I can do right now is

`Recieve IF (condition_1 AND condition_2)`

I'm trying to get to something like this
[image]

which "translates" to 
`Recieve IF (cooking AND (fish OR seafood))`

Has anyone been able to achieve this from the gem?

Comment: Have you tried using `value_in` form their Query class? That should do the trick but I am not familiar with this library, just my best guess. https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/parse/query.rb#L86

Comment: That `value_in` is the one that performs the "contain one of" part of the picture. I'm looking to 'AND' several `value_in`s

Comment: Sorry mixed things up here. The Query class also has a contains_all method which translates to the $all operator.This should allow you to select all objects that are subscribed to channel A, B and C. Is it that what you're looking for? See https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-arrays and https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/parse/query.rb#L96

Comment: Not exactly, that is what I already have implemented. In my example, the user will receive the push only if he is subscribed to the `cooking` channel AND any of the `fish` or `seafood` channels. Using `contains_all` would send the push if the user is subscribed to `cooking` and `fish` and `seafood` .

Comment: Hi Sebastialonso, just a quick question since you've been using Rails with Parse for Push notifications : have you created PFUsers along with PFInstallations and used Parse IOS SDK from ios app to query directly badge count for instance?

Comment: Hi @stefano_cdn! No I'm not, I'm against Parse having my and my customers data on its servers. I'm using it for the Push functionality only.

Having said that, I think you can accomplish that using a specific query: instead of requiring channels, ask for badge.

Comment: Thx for your answer! How do you deal with your badge counts? You update and query the badge count through the rails back-end and then parse rest api? I know it's possible to do that but wondering if it's a good option..

Comment: Actually I don't think we deal with badge counts. We don't need the user's attention in the application to modify content. I'm sorry I can help you further!